# Computing uniform distribution probabilities with two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification, uniform-distribution

How can I compute $P(X > 3Y)$ where $X, Y \sim U(-1, 1)$? I got $1/2$ since $\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{3y}^{1} \frac{1}{4} \mathop{dx dy} = 1/2$ but it seems wrong since $P(X > Y)$ should be $1/2$.

How about $P(X > 3Y \mid X > 0)?$ I think this is $(1/6)/2 = 1/12$ by drawing a picture but not completely sure.

Here's my picture for the first part:

[image]

Comment: Intuitively, we have P(X>Y) = 1/2. So would that make P(X>3Y) = 1/2 any sense?

Comment: Hmm.. let me try to recalculate.

Comment: Curiously, it is still 1/2 because of the centrally symmetric scenario we have here.

Comment: Ah ok. That's what I thought. Thanks for the clarification

Comment: And go with the pictures (areas in the XY plane). And you can verify it with your integrals as well.

Comment: Does the second probability equalling $1/12$ make sense ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Independence of $X$ and $Y$ is essential for this. Otherwise you cannot compute $P(X>3Y)$.

Your integral is wrong. The integral from $3y$ to $1$ w.r.t. $x$ appears only when $3y<1$ or $y <\frac  1 3$.  Similarly you have to make sure that $3y >-1$. So the correct integral is $\int_{-1/3}^{1/3} \int_{3y}^{1} \frac  1  4 dxdy+\int_{-1}^{-1/3} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac  1  4 dxdy$.

For the conditional probability compute $\int_{0}^{1/3} \int_{3y}^{1} \frac  1  4 dxdy+\int_{-1/3}^{0} \int_{0}^{1} \frac  1  4 dxdy+\int_{-1}^{-1/3} \int_{0}^{1} \frac  1  4 dxdy$.  and divide by $P(X>0)$ which is $\frac 1  2$.

Comment: How come my pictures don't match up with your integrals? I'm drawing a square with the line $y = x/3$. With some geometry, I compute the area of the region, and my answer is the ratio of that area to the total area of the square, which is $4$. I end up getting $1/2$ as the answer.

Comment: It should be clear that $\int_{3y}^{1}dx$ cannot appear when $3y >1$. Did you get a triangle plus a rectangle? Check your calculation again.

Comment: I agree that $\int_{3y}^{1} \mathop{dx}$ shouldn't appear when $3y > 1$. I'm getting a triangle and a rectangle. I've just updated my post with the picture for your reference.

Comment: @Wan I made some mistakes in my answer and I have corrected them. Your picture is correct. But your integrals have wrong limits.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I compute $P(X > 3Y)$ where $X, Y \sim U(-1, 1)$? I got $1/2$ since $\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{3y}^{1} \frac{1}{4} \mathop{dx dy} = 1/2$ but it seems wrong since $P(X > Y)$ should be $1/2$.

As your diagram shows, both $X$ and $Y$ are distributed symmetrically around $0$, and a line through the origin will bisect the $(-1,1)^2$ square whatever is its gradient.   Thusly, you should actually anticipate that: $$\forall m\in\Bbb R~.\mathsf P(Y<mX)=1/2$$

> How about $P(X > 3Y \mid X > 0)?$ I think this is $(1/6)/2 = 1/12$ by drawing a picture but not completely sure.

$$\mathsf P(X>3Y\mid X>0)=\dfrac{\displaystyle\int_0^1\int_{-1}^{x/3}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\, \mathrm d y\,\mathrm d x}{1/2}=\dfrac 7{12}$$

$[\small\text{Note: }\mathsf P(X>3Y\mid X>0, Y>0)=1/6, \mathsf P(X>3Y\mid X>0,Y\leq 0)=1]$

---

And, of course:

$$\mathsf P(X>3Y)=\int_{-1}^1\int_{-1}^{x/3} \dfrac 14\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm d x = \dfrac 12$$